# Replace html with html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to replace a big section of html code (the content on the side) with other html code.

I have used the JavaScript code below:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
```

The thing is that I can't replace html code that got the `""` characters in it. Can someone please help me?

I should ad that I´m a beginner with JavaScript and as of now I want to stay away from jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML ='text to be replaced with "" ';
```

or with

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML ="text to be replaced with \"\"";
```

or with

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML ='text to be replaced with \'\'';
```

( **\"** is the escape sequence for the character **"** and in javascript you can use either **'** or **"** for the strings)

here the [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/pect2o0b/)

Comment: Will be nice to mention that `\"` or `\'` are escape sequences. You cloud have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Using_special_characters_in_strings).